# ContextIO API not working

Tags: php, email, github, contextio

Hi I am using contextIO api for fetch emails.I got a code from GitHub ,but it shows some errors.I am using this code ,

```
include_once("class.contextio.php");

// see https://console.context.io/#settings to get your consumer key and consumer secret.
$contextIO = new ContextIO('asssasas','sdsd1111sdsdsd');
$accountId = null;

// list your accounts
$r = $contextIO->listAccounts();//print_r($r);
foreach ($r->getData() as $account) {
    echo $account['id'] . "\t" . join(", ", $account['email_addresses']) . "\n";
    if (is_null($accountId)) {
        $accountId = $account['id'];
    }
}
```

But it shows a n error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object
```

Is it need a seperate gmail authentication? anyone please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the functions in the ContextIO library return a ContextIOResponse object, or `false` if the API returns an http error code. Check for `if($r !== false)` before you call `getData()` on `$r` and you should be good to go!

(Note: I work on the context.io team and am currently the primary developer on the PHP libraries.)